# Some details about C's integer type

Tags: c

A variable named ***verybig*** is declared like this in C：

```
long long verybig = 12345678908642;
```

And then output it in specific format:

```
printf("verybig= %lld and not %ld\n", verybig, verybig);
```

These code samples are examples in *"C Primer Plus, 6th Edition"*, and the expected output is:

```
verybig= 12345678908642 and not 1942899938
```

The book explains that this is because the `%ld` specifier only views the value stored in the last 32bits instead of the full value.
However, when I run the code myself (with gcc version 5.4.0, 64-bit OS, C11 standard), I get the following output:

```
verybig= 12345678908642 and not 12345678908642
```

As you can see, the `%ld` specifier seems to not work. Would you please expain it for me?

Comment: Are you perhaps on a Linux machine? `"%ld"` is the format specifier for a `long` which may or may not be 64-bits. It seems it is on your machine.

Comment: I fixed your formatting. Please consult https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for future posts

Comment: Size of integer types on different systems can differ.

Comment: Have you tried to compile it with the `-m32` option ?

Comment: It depends on your machine.

Comment: If this is indeed what the book says, its seems to not be worth the money. It makes a lot of implicit assumptions it fails to communicate to you.

Comment: Looking at reality statistically, it's safe to say a good programming book does not exist.

Comment: @DeiDei Statistically you can only claim it is very rare :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, looked at this book, and it says: *Here is the output on one system (results can vary):*

Comment: Just as a suggestion: I personally think [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) is a very good read in that regard.
And IF you know what int width you actually want/need, check out e.g. [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C standard only requires integer types to have a minimum size. For the type `long`, the only requirement (C11 5.2.4.2.1) is that `long` can at least fit an integer of size 2<sup>31</sup>-1. This means that `long` *is at least* 4 bytes, but that a compiler is free to make it larger, such as for example 8 bytes.

Similarly, `long long` is only guaranteed to fit at least the value 2<sup>63</sup>-1.

The format specifier `%ld` assumes a parameter of type `long`. `%lld` assumes a parameter of type `long long`. If you use the wrong format specifiers compared to the types passed, then strictly speaking your program has undefined behavior (C11 7.21.6.1/7).

---

As for your book, it makes the following silent assumptions:

- `long long` is 8 bytes
- `long` is 4 bytes
- Printing a `long long` with `%ld` gives some manner of deterministic output.
- The system is using 2's complement, little endian, no trap representations.

None of these assumptions are guaranteed by the standard and the book should mention this. Your particular system most likely has `long` as 8 bytes and therefore you get the mentioned result.

---

As for how to do professional programming, the types `long` and `long long` are mostly useless in production-quality code, for these very reasons. Professional programmes instead use the types from `stdint.h`, such as `int32_t` and `int64_t`, which are *guaranteed* to be 32 and 64 bit respectively, with 2's complement representation. This makes it possible to write portable C code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!It seems like my OS give the **long** type 64bits...I replace the %ld with %d,then everthing goes right.

Comment: @罗通侯君 Similarly, you could `#include <inttypes.h>` and play around with `printf("verybig= %"PRId64 " and not %"PRId32 "\n", verybig, verybig);` These are the format specifiers used for `int64_t` and `int32_t`.